# storyboard apply push without clicking on Button for(modal,push,custom)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

Storyboard push modal custom segue.

I am working on storyboards and on click on a button on one view a web service gets called. After its success I need to push to other view controller. For this I have added a view controller and set its class from inspector to a view.

But I have not applied any segue on storyboard but I want to push to that view controller as

`[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller animated:YES];`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a navigationController to you view and then push to the next view.

Comment: is there any other way that a storyboards support to move from one view to otheri dont want to use(push,modal,custom property or navigation controller.) I just want to move from one view controller to other where api returns success